# Long Running Outbound HTTP Request from Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

Given the fact that Azure will remove your instance from your Role and shut it down from time to time, is there any way to execute long-running HTTP requests from inside Azure? Typically, these will be initiated by a Worker Role.

Some 3rd party web APIs take longer than the 5 minutes Azure gives you as a warning when it kills your instance.

Comment: When a hard drive fails, you don't get a 5-minute warning, so your app is going to have to be resilient to being interrupted during requests anyway. Once it's resilient to that, does it really matter that you'll be shut down once every month or two when Windows Azure patches its host servers?

Comment: I really like your point here. I have to agree with you. In our case, it will not be so much oriented around resilience. We can handle the faults, but the API vendors cannot, for example. In those cases, fees are incurred because there are various distributed workflows and daisy chains of APIs running, and no way to get the horse back into the barn. I think this may become more of an SLA matter between our platform and its consumers.